# Why is chosenness removed in the evening prayer?

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, maariv

In the morning service we say Ahavah Rabbah:

> Baruch atta HaShem ha-bocher b'ammo Yisrael be-ahava (Blessed are You, O Lord, Who has chosen His people Israel with love.)

In the evening service we say Ahavat Olam:

> Baruch atta HaShem ohev 'ammo Yisrael  (Blessed are You, O Lord, Who loves His people Israel.)

Why is chosenness removed in the evening prayer?

Comment: DId you mean "replaced with Ohev"?

Comment: @AlBerko אהב is present in both versions